# Повторное socket подключение

Tags: node.js, javascript, сокет

Я открыл страницу один раз. Через пару минут в консоли было несколько логов о коннекте, хотя должен быть один.

Почему так и как это исправить?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('connection');
});
```

Comment: чем Вы подключаетесь, приведите более полный код, который можно протестить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Современные браузеры посылают много дополнительных запросов, в том числе

- запрос favicon
- предзапрос данных для ускоренной загрузки

Чтобы понять, что вызывается, логируйте в консоль урл запроса

Для чистоты эксперемента, подключайтесь не браузером, а терминалом.

Например в виндовс так:

```
telnet localhost portnumber
GET / HTTP/1.1
```